# Escape forward slash in Ruby url helper

Tags: ruby, uri, haml, staticmatic

Setuping a staticMatic project using `/index.html`:

`@slug = current_page.gsub(/\.html/, '')`

returns `"/index(.html)"`, but should be `/index`

---

Changing term corrects: - `@slug = current_page.gsub("/", "").gsub(".html", "")` as found in:

`https://github.com/adamstac/staticmatic-bootstrap/blob/master/src/helpers/application_helper.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the beginning "/" after you've stripped the html simply execute this (which will do both in one command):

```
current_page.gsub(/\.html/, '').gsub(/\//,''))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I also discovered this, when changing my search terms more and more: 

- @slug = current_page.gsub("/", "").gsub(".html", "")

It was in - http://github.com/adamstac/staticmatic-bootstrap